What to do to pass dictionary to recursivetextsplitter in and get doc to embed in chromadb
I was passing text to split for embeding in chromadb which I was passing through recursivetextsplitter of langchain library, also what other ways to do it...
I tried to convert it into text and then pass it to embed but in embeddings you must have to pass documents , is ther any function who takes straight away text...
here is the code snippets that I ran
